# Execute JS server-site to generate hash for xhr

Tags: javascript, php, logging, hash, web-scraping

There is a [scrapebot-proof form](https://auth.gripon.ru/). 
The login & password inputs have the obfuscated *name* attribute:

```
<input id="login-username" name="r0pUsRqARu" value=""
 type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Login">
```

Based on those inputs (incl. login and password values) and hidden char input field the hash value is generated client-side by js functionality ([md5.js](https://auth.gripon.ru/md5.js)).

```
$("#btn-login").click(function(){
     var ser = $( "#loginform" ).serialize();  
     $.post("/post.php",ser+"&hash="+md5(ser),function(){
         location.replace("/logged.php");});
     });
```

The form is serialized and is sent as POST xhr (ajax) to *post.php* for logging in (see the code above).

I want to write **php script to automatically log in through the form**.

No problem with getting the form on server, fetching name attributes, pasting login/password values and requesting by POST xhr to */post.php* with serialized string.

```
cV2sD3JzH2=login&3JX2zJ7QlC=password&char=%C2%AA&hash=...
```

Yet, since the *hash is generated client-side by js* (by md5.js), **I can't generate hash server side by php**... What's the way out?

Some thoughts:

1. Transform *md5.js* into a server-side script and execute it to produce hash. How?
2. Use AngularJS (or similar JS framework on server) to run md5.js on server to produce hash. *Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with AngularJS.*

### Update

Sorry, I've presumsiously thought I could fetch the obfuscated *name* attribute values and *char* input value server-side. Yet, as **RamRaider** mentioned, `without javascript enabled they are named *email* and *password*` and no hidden *char* input is in the html when javascript is disabled.
So, when fetching content with php cUrl (no js server-side), I have a *clean form* without hidden *char* input and unobfuscated name values, see it below (removed styling):

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="/post.php">
  <input id="login-username" type="text"  name="email" value="" >                   
  <input id="login-password" type="password" name="password" >
  <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>
</form>
```

**Again JS tricks that are not avail at server-side. How can I fix it?**

I was seraching for JS inserting somewhere new attribute values, but in vain. It should be smth. like the following:

```
$('login-form').attr('name', <new value>);
```

Comment: What about PHP's md5: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php?  Or if that isn't quite the same as the JS version, then port the JS version to PHP.

Comment: @jfriend00, are the code in md5.js is the unique code, or it generates md5 hash as other languages do? Any proof of it; any docs?

Comment: without javascript enabled they are named `email` and `password`

Comment: @RamRaider, yet obviously you can't submit the form without js: form's *Login* button is just a block element... No hash generation without js, no form serialization, no xhr...

Comment: I don't know where the md5.js that's being used there comes from or where the doc is for it.  You can test it to see if it generates the same results as PHP's MD5 function on a bunch of different inputs.  Or, you can attempt to find the author of that md5.js and ask them.  Or, you can just port it to PHP (it's just math) and be sure you have the same algorithm.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you very much. They are true the same. You might see it [here](http://tarex.ru/testdir/designio/mytry2.php?login=test&password=test1). Compare it with md5.js hash that I store there in localStorage! Make it an answer and I check it up!

Comment: @RamRaider, thank you for `without javascript enabled they are named *email* and *password*`. Please look at my update.

Comment: I think that much could be learned by decoding the function in the code - the one that appears after the `md5.js` script - I had a go and then gave up to do other stuff.

Comment: @RamRaider, how to decode such a weird function? Any hints, services, docs?

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious where the `md5.js` that's being used there comes from or where the doc is for it. As such, you have these options:

1. You can test it to see if it generates the same results as PHP's MD5 function on a bunch of different inputs.
2. You can attempt to find the author of that md5.js and ask them.
3. You can just port it to PHP (it's just math) and be sure you have the same algorithm.
4. You can study the source of both implementations to see if you can conclude whether it's implementing the exact same algorithm.

I'd suggest you start with the first option since that's the easiest way to immediately tell whether they might be the same algorithm or not.

Comment: I've done the first option and concluded it's true. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin - I answered the first part of your question which you told me to put in an answer.  Now, you've made a new part of the question which can only be solved by reverse engineering what the obfuscated script is doing or by actually running the page server-side to fetch the desired values from a fake-DOM server-side.