# Deobfuscate JS obfuscated script for performing it server-side

Tags: javascript, php, html, obfuscation, deobfuscation

How can I deobfuscate a javaScript code? It's [here](https://auth.gripon.ru/) (inside of the very last script tag).

Basically I know what it does (obfuscating the form's login/password name attribute value and adds to the form a hidden input with name='char' and random value, see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34961422/1230477)). I want to decode the script to know how it performs obfuscation, so that **I could imitate it server-side** (with php).

This [tool](http://www.ilearnzone.net/2013/10/js-decompress-and-beautifier-decode.html) can't decode it.

I've done some deobfuscation by eveluating `hd` object. I took the parts of code (separated by semicolon `;`) and eveluated them:

```
<script>
    var hd =~[];
    hd={___:++hd,$$$$:(![]+"")[hd],__$:++hd,$_$_:(![]+"")[hd],_$_:++hd,$_$$:({}+"")[hd],$$_$:(hd[hd]+"")[hd],_$$:++hd,$$$_:(!""+"")[hd],$__:++hd,$_$:++hd,$$__:({}+"")[hd],$$_:++hd,$$$:++hd,$___:++hd,$__$:++hd};

    hd.$_=(hd.$_=hd+"")[hd.$_$]+(hd._$=hd.$_[hd.__$])+(hd.$$=(hd.$+"")[hd.__$])+((!hd)+"")[hd._$$]+(hd.__=hd.$_[hd.$$_])+(hd.$=(!""+"")[hd.__$])+(hd._=(!""+"")[hd._$_])+hd.$_[hd.$_$]+hd.__+hd._$+hd.$;

    hd.$$=hd.$+(!""+"")[hd._$$]+hd.__+hd._+hd.$+hd.$$;  

    hd.$=(hd.___)[hd.$_][hd.$_];  

    console.log('hd: '); 
    console.dir(hd);
    console.log('hd length: ' + Object.keys(hd).length);
</script>
```

The output of it you might see [there](http://tarex.ru/testdir/designio/test.html) in browser console.

Yet the last part of the code, obviously is a function calling itself:

```
hd.$(hd.$(... _+"\"")())();
```

`hd.$` is object's function, see the figure:
[image]

But I do not know how to decode it. 
I've tried to replace all the instances of the object, ex. hd.$$$$, hd.$_$ etc. in the rest of the code but the result is only like [this](http://tarex.ru/testdir/designio/result.html). No clue how to move on.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using Node.JS then you could run it server-side ;)

Comment: @JulianKnight, Is Node.JS compatible with php?

Comment: Try those deobfuscators and see which works for you: http://www.kahusecurity.com/2014/javascript-deobfuscation-tools-redux/

Comment: @JohannesJander, thank you. I'll try them later.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin: Compatible? In the sense that you can run them side-by-side on the same platform, yes. Probably not what you meant though. Node.JS is another scripting language based server like PHP or PYTHON but uses JavaScript so you can use the same language on both the server and the client. It is fully cross-platform even on embedded systems and has many thousands of libraries to do just about anything. Like PHP but vastly more flexible. Requires more access to the OS though so not always available on cheap hosting platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `hd` object is constructed, no other variable assignments are made, it is just building a large string to parse into a function.

So using your resulting `hd` object, I extracted the part building the string an got this:

```
"return\"docu\155e\156t.\147et\105le\155e\156t\102\171\111d('lo\147\151\156fo\162\155').\151\156\156e\162\110\124\115\114\40=\40'<d\151\166\40\163t\171le=\"\155a\162\147\151\156-botto\155:\4025\160\170\"\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160\"><\163\160a\156\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160-addo\156\"><\151\40cla\163\163=\"\147l\171\160\150\151co\156\40\147l\171\160\150\151co\156-u\163e\162\"></\151></\163\160a\156><\151\156\160ut\40\151d=\"lo\147\151\156-u\163e\162\156a\155e\"\40t\171\160e=\"te\170t\"\40cla\163\163=\"fo\162\155-co\156t\162ol\"\40\156a\155e=\"\130\161\125\106\1603\107\156e\147\"\40\166alue=\"\"\40\160lace\150olde\162=\"\114o\147\151\156\"></d\151\166><d\151\166\40\163t\171le=\"\155a\162\147\151\156-botto\155:\4025\160\170\"\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160\"><\163\160a\156\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160-addo\156\"><\151\40cla\163\163=\"\147l\171\160\150\151co\156\40\147l\171\160\150\151co\156-loc\153\"></\151></\163\160a\156><\151\156\160ut\40\151d=\"lo\147\151\156-\160a\163\163\167o\162d\"\40t\171\160e=\"\160a\163\163\167o\162d\"\40cla\163\163=\"fo\162\155-co\156t\162ol\"\40\156a\155e=\"\171l\110\156\110\161\150\104\1262\"\40\160lace\150olde\162=\"\120a\163\163\167o\162d\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40cla\163\163=\"c\150ec\153bo\170\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<label>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<\151\156\160ut\40\151d=\"lo\147\151\156-\162e\155e\155be\162\"\40t\171\160e=\"c\150ec\153bo\170\"\40\156a\155e=\"\162e\155e\155be\162\"\40\166alue=\"1\">\40\122e\155e\155be\162\40\155e\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</label>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40\163t\171le=\"\155a\162\147\151\156-to\160:10\160\170\"\40cla\163\163=\"fo\162\155-\147\162ou\160\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40cla\163\163=\"col-\163\155-12\40co\156t\162ol\163\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<a\40\151d=\"bt\156-lo\147\151\156\"\40\150\162ef=\"#\"\40cla\163\163=\"bt\156\40bt\156-\163ucce\163\163\">\114o\147\151\156\40\40</a>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<\151\156\160ut\40t\171\160e=\"\150\151dde\156\"\40\156a\155e=\"c\150a\162\"\40\166alue=\"&\156ot;\">';\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40$(\"#bt\156-lo\147\151\156\").cl\151c\153(fu\156ct\151o\156(){\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\166a\162\40\163e\162\40=\40$(\40\"#lo\147\151\156fo\162\155\"\40).\163e\162\151al\151\172e();\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40$.\160o\163t(\"/\160o\163t.\160\150\160\",\163e\162+\"&\150a\163\150=\"+\155d5(\163e\162),fu\156ct\151o\156(){locat\151o\156.\162e\160lace(\"/lo\147\147ed.\160\150\160\");});\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40});\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\"";
```

This gets us halfway. But a lot of characters are URI-encoded (\xxx). I did a simple regex replacement to decode these values:

```
var raw = "return\"docu\155e\156t.\147et\105le\155e\156t\102\171\111d('lo\147\151\156fo\162\155').\151\156\156e\162\110\124\115\114\40=\40'<d\151\166\40\163t\171le=\"\155a\162\147\151\156-botto\155:\4025\160\170\"\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160\"><\163\160a\156\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160-addo\156\"><\151\40cla\163\163=\"\147l\171\160\150\151co\156\40\147l\171\160\150\151co\156-u\163e\162\"></\151></\163\160a\156><\151\156\160ut\40\151d=\"lo\147\151\156-u\163e\162\156a\155e\"\40t\171\160e=\"te\170t\"\40cla\163\163=\"fo\162\155-co\156t\162ol\"\40\156a\155e=\"\130\161\125\106\1603\107\156e\147\"\40\166alue=\"\"\40\160lace\150olde\162=\"\114o\147\151\156\"></d\151\166><d\151\166\40\163t\171le=\"\155a\162\147\151\156-botto\155:\4025\160\170\"\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160\"><\163\160a\156\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160-addo\156\"><\151\40cla\163\163=\"\147l\171\160\150\151co\156\40\147l\171\160\150\151co\156-loc\153\"></\151></\163\160a\156><\151\156\160ut\40\151d=\"lo\147\151\156-\160a\163\163\167o\162d\"\40t\171\160e=\"\160a\163\163\167o\162d\"\40cla\163\163=\"fo\162\155-co\156t\162ol\"\40\156a\155e=\"\171l\110\156\110\161\150\104\1262\"\40\160lace\150olde\162=\"\120a\163\163\167o\162d\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40cla\163\163=\"\151\156\160ut-\147\162ou\160\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40cla\163\163=\"c\150ec\153bo\170\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<label>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<\151\156\160ut\40\151d=\"lo\147\151\156-\162e\155e\155be\162\"\40t\171\160e=\"c\150ec\153bo\170\"\40\156a\155e=\"\162e\155e\155be\162\"\40\166alue=\"1\">\40\122e\155e\155be\162\40\155e\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</label>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40\163t\171le=\"\155a\162\147\151\156-to\160:10\160\170\"\40cla\163\163=\"fo\162\155-\147\162ou\160\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<d\151\166\40cla\163\163=\"col-\163\155-12\40co\156t\162ol\163\">\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<a\40\151d=\"bt\156-lo\147\151\156\"\40\150\162ef=\"#\"\40cla\163\163=\"bt\156\40bt\156-\163ucce\163\163\">\114o\147\151\156\40\40</a>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40</d\151\166>\\\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40<\151\156\160ut\40t\171\160e=\"\150\151dde\156\"\40\156a\155e=\"c\150a\162\"\40\166alue=\"&\156ot;\">';\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40$(\"#bt\156-lo\147\151\156\").cl\151c\153(fu\156ct\151o\156(){\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\166a\162\40\163e\162\40=\40$(\40\"#lo\147\151\156fo\162\155\"\40).\163e\162\151al\151\172e();\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40$.\160o\163t(\"/\160o\163t.\160\150\160\",\163e\162+\"&\150a\163\150=\"+\155d5(\163e\162),fu\156ct\151o\156(){locat\151o\156.\162e\160lace(\"/lo\147\147ed.\160\150\160\");});\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40});\12\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\40\"";

var decoded = raw.replace(/\\\d+/g, function(match) {
    return window.decodeURIComponent(match);
});
```

This gave me the following (tidied up a little and formatted):

```
document.getElementById('loginform').innerHTML = '
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="XqUFp3Gneg" value="" placeholder="Login">
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
        </span>
        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="ylHnHqhDV2" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">
                Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="char" value="&not;">
';

$("#btn-login").click(function(){
    var ser = $( "#loginform" ).serialize();
    $.post("/post.php",
        ser + "&hash=" + md5(ser),
        function() { location.replace("/logged.php"); }
    );
});
```

In other words it is serializing the form values using jquery [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), then creating an md5 hash of that serialized value and passing that as the `hash` querystring to the server call.

Comment: thank you. It's exactly what it should be. Yet, do I need to decode this script each time I query the form with obfuscated code? Those obfuscated name attr values and char input value are different each request (I could see it by fetching `form.serialized()` value). Do these  `name="XqUFp3Gneg"` `name="ylHnHqhDV2"` and `name="char" value="&not;"` are correlated at target server? What do you think? If they are not correlated, I could randomly generate them by php and submit the form. Otherwise target server may check their authentiveness and reject my own name values and char value.

Comment: also could you explain more how you've reached this: "return\"docu\155e\156t.\147et\105le\155e\156t\102\171\111d('lo\147\.... ?

Comment: what tool can I use to automatically perform this kind of decoding server-side?

Comment: if you view source on the page you linked to, then compare to the generated code above, you can see the `form-control` names are different and the `<input type="hidden" name="char">` is added. This script is rendered by the server, so it must be generating the names there. This makes sense from a security point of view.

Comment: I don't know exactly how you are interacting with this page on your server-side - are basically doing a http request and parsing it? But I would aim to avoid de-obfuscating it every time and try to find a way to use the de-obfuscated code as-is, e.g. use the same form element names each time.

Comment: `This script is rendered by the server, so it must be generating the names there.` - sure, yet **each form load** this script is different since **those names are different** and char value is **different too*8!

Comment: I got to "return\"docu\155e\156t.\147et\105le\155e\156t\102\171\111d('lo\1 by just copying and pasting the rest of the code in the `script` tag and excluding the brackets to actually run it. It is a bit hit-and-miss, but you can generally break it up by the semi-colons as you started to do. the I created a `hd` object using what you had posted and just ran the string generation code and out it into a variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101579/discussion-between-rhumborl-and-igor-savinkin).